# Unable to run C++ compile (VS 2013 Crash)

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013

I was interested in primes, so I whipped up this (sloppy, as I'm not very experienced in C++) snippet:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{

for (int i = 3; i < 1000; i += 2)
{
    bool prime = true;

    for (int u = 3; u * u <= i; u += 2)
    {
        if (i % u == 0)
        {
            prime = false;

            break; 
        }
    }

    if (prime)
    {
        std::cout << "Prime: " << i << std::endl;
    }
}

return 0;
}
```

My old Java port of this idea works perfectly, so I thought I would optimize and move it to C++, however, when I compile and run "Primes", I instead get VS2013 throwing up by what appears to be it opening a TON of "Watch" and "Memory " windows, then halting...

Kinda like this... [image: Screeching halt; death by memory watcher]

This is a fresh Empty Project, with a source `Primes.cpp`, with this snippet by itself. I've restarted VS2013 about 5 times, same result. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You have created a GUI application. And then added a new entry point for a command line application. The code you've shown is not all the code there is. At any rate, your IDE is doing what is to be expected. You'll have to change your expectations. Or set up a command line application instead.

Comment: @IInspectable I just recreated the project as another Empty Project, and I did it again, as a Win32 Console Application.  Both attempts saw the same results.  I do not see a specifically-named "command line application" template, if there is one, or I might be missing something, which hopefully you can help out with.

Comment: Seek ye Win32 Console Application

Comment: *"Win32 Console Application"* is the appropriate project template. One more note: When you start a console application under the debugger, the console window is closed when the process terminates. If you start the application without a debugger (Debug -> Start Without Debugging), the console window remains open, until you press a key.

Comment: Also look up Sieve of Eratosthenes. Hard to beat it for prime hunting.

Comment: Even using "Win32 Console Application", the debugger still opens 50 or so windows while the program is running, regardless of type of project, or number of iterations run in the program.  However, this only occurs when the program is debugged, and simply running it w/o the debugger will work fine.  It's still quite annoying though, having to choose that option when it doesn't seem like there's a good reason to freak out like that.